# Is the source code of the demo at WWDC 09, Session 304 available?

Tags: iphone, wwdc

At WWDC 09 in Session 304 "Game Development for iPhone, Part 1 (Graphics, Audio)", about 6 minutes after start of the Session, they showed off a small but nice OpenGL ES game demo and repeating over and over again how easy it is to implement. Is that source code of the demo available somewhere for download?

Comment: If you were at the event, you should have access to all the presentations.   You should have gotten an email explaining how to access the videos and related resources.

Comment: I think I missed that. My head was and still is completely full with a ton of stuff to grok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is, the way to get it would be from here:

http://developer.apple.com/products/videos.html

Since you presumably went to WWDC, you should get the videos for free.  Underneath the purchase section, there are some help links, and one of them is about getting the activation email re-sent.  Once you get the link to access the videos in iTunes, any sample code should be available in there.

Comment: Thanks. Had a look into it, but it seems I can't find the source for that demo :-(

Comment: I cannot find the WWDC2009 videos and example code any more..